# class method not found return type defaults to 'id'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting the following error:

```
class method '+view' not found return type defaults to 'id'
```

Using this code:

```
[window addSubview:[ButtonsViewController view]];
```

Can someone help please?

here is the full code:

```
    #import "openURLAppDelegate.h"
#import "ButtonsViewController.h"
#include "ButtonsViewController.h"




@implementation openURLAppDelegate


@synthesize window;
@synthesize ButtonsViewController;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {



[window addSubview:[ButtonsViewController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}


- (void)dealloc {
[ButtonsViewController release];
[window release];
[super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: `ButtonsViewController` is a Class. You cannot synthesize or release a class. You should create an instance of this class for this purpose. Also the `include` directive should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If view is the UIView of your controller you should call this on your controller's instance and not on the class.

Comment: Well, if that worked for you, consider to mark the answer as correct